# .NET NUnit test - Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

When class used `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` run in unit test, the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is `null`.

Is there some option how define `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` during unit testing?

Comment: You could create a mock Assembly instance and use that for your unit tests.

Comment: Use one of the Assembly class static methods, such as GetAssembly() or GetCallingAssembly().

Comment: @Bernard: I can use only Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), other methods has different meaning...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could do something like this with `Rhino Mocks`:  Encapsulate the `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` call into a class with interface `IAssemblyLoader` and inject it into the class your are testing. This is not tested but something along the lines of this:

```
[Test] public void TestSomething() {
  // arrange
  var stubbedAssemblyLoader = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IAssemblyLoader>();
  stubbedAssemblyLoader.Stub(x => x.GetEntryAssembly()).Return(Assembly.LoadFrom("assemblyFile"));

  // act      
  var myClassUnderTest = new MyClassUnderTest(stubbedAssemblyLoader);
  var result = myClassUnderTest.MethodToTest();

  // assert
  Assert.AreEqual("expected result", result);
}

public interface IAssemblyLoader {
  Assembly GetEntryAssembly();
}
public class AssemblyLoader : IAssemblyLoader {
  public Assembly GetEntryAssembly() {
    return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
  }
}
```

Update: `Rhino Mocks` is no longer actively maintained but could do something similar with other mocking libraries such as [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq)

Answer (score 67):

Implement the SetEntryAssembly(Assembly assembly) method given in

http://frostwave.googlecode.com/svn-history/r75/trunk/F2DUnitTests/Code/AssemblyUtilities.cs

to your unit test project.

```
         /// <summary>
        /// Use as first line in ad hoc tests (needed by XNA specifically)
        /// </summary>
        public static void SetEntryAssembly()
        {
            SetEntryAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows setting the Entry Assembly when needed. 
        /// Use AssemblyUtilities.SetEntryAssembly() as first line in XNA ad hoc tests
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="assembly">Assembly to set as entry assembly</param>
        public static void SetEntryAssembly(Assembly assembly)
        {
            AppDomainManager manager = new AppDomainManager();
            FieldInfo entryAssemblyfield = manager.GetType().GetField("m_entryAssembly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            entryAssemblyfield.SetValue(manager, assembly);

            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            FieldInfo domainManagerField = domain.GetType().GetField("_domainManager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            domainManagerField.SetValue(domain, manager);
        }
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://github.com/lyphtec/LyphTEC.Repository.Dapper/blob/master/src/LyphTEC.Repository.Dapper.Tests/AssemblyUtils.cs

Comment: AppDomainManager  isn't available in .netcoreapp1.x/netcoreapp2.x /netstandard2.0 https://apisof.net/catalog/System.AppDomainManager

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant!  Thanks!