# Why does GetEntryAssembly return null with a unit test?

Tags: c#, mstest, system.reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET NUnit test - Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337201/net-nunit-test-assembly-getentryassembly-is-null)

`System.Reflection.Assembly assem = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();`

The code returns null when running a unit test.  I am testing for a third party utility that also returns null.  I cannot distinguish between the two programs if both of them return null.

What can I do to determine I am running in a unit test context programatically?  I do not want to add it to the configuration file because of the point of failure that creates.  E.G. I forgot to flip the bit so it gets pushed to Prod in dev mode.  My boss pushes to prod.  I do not want him to have to repeat a job or change configuration files regularly for obvious political motivations.

Comment: 1) [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() Returns Nothing when running from a Unit Test](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vststest/thread/7ff8caae-56c6-4baa-94c9-7224f69dbd17) 2) [.NET NUnit test - Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337201/net-nunit-test-assembly-getentryassembly-is-null)

Comment: What kind of unit testing framework are you using?

Comment: @svick updated question tags.