# Instantiating a .NET form in Runtime mode inside a unit test

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, devexpress, licensing

In order to protect against poor designer merges that mess up control initialization, I decided to add some "unit tests" that try to create instances of my System.Windows.Forms.Form objects, like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMyForm()
{
    var form = new MyForm();//if exception is thrown, fail test...
}
```

Unfortunately, DevExpress doesn't seem to like having its controls instantiated from within the unit test runner and it shows a nagging splash screen with "License expired" that requires user interaction in order to continue running the tests. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours of thorough digging, I discovered that `System.ComponentModel.Design.RuntimeLicenseContext.GetSavedLicenseKey()` is being called by DevExpress and this method makes a call to `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`, which happens to [return null when called from within a unit test](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7ff8caae-56c6-4baa-94c9-7224f69dbd17/assemblygetentryassembly-returns-nothing-when-running-from-a-unit-test?forum=vststest), and this makes DevExpress believe that its being used in designer mode, which indeed requires a valid license.

Having this clue, I managed to find a really [underrated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21888521/1174378) from user [@Manjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270903/manjay) that provides an elegant solution to this problem by using reflection. I took the liberty to provide the following slightly modified version of [Jamie Cansdale](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/)'s code, which can be found [here](http://frostwave.googlecode.com/svn-history/r75/trunk/F2DUnitTests/Code/AssemblyUtilities.cs):

```
public static void SetEntryAssembly()
{
    if (Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    AppDomainManager manager = new AppDomainManager();
    FieldInfo entryAssemblyfield = manager.GetType().GetField("m_entryAssembly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (entryAssemblyfield != null)
    {
        entryAssemblyfield.SetValue(manager, assembly);
    }

    AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    FieldInfo domainManagerField = domain.GetType().GetField("_domainManager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (domainManagerField != null)
    {
        domainManagerField.SetValue(domain, manager);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out `Coded UI Tests` for testing the UI of WinForms applications.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx

Comment: Neat! I might consider switching to such tests in the future.